# Search multiple values in excel and highlight them

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to search 105 numbers from a list of 650 numbers and highlight them if found. Is there an easier way to do this?  Eg . Column x in exceel has 10 values and i need to search 5values in column x and highlight it. (Ofcourse the number is larger in actual)

Comment: Please post a sample structure and how you want to highlight these 105 numbers

Comment: Its fairly simple. Out of the 10 values in column x, i know of 5 values that needs to be highlighted from the 10 values.

Comment: Which Excel version are you using?

Comment: Microsoft excel 2010 version

Answer (score 1):

If you have the short list in column **A** and the long list in column **B** like:

[image]

running this macro:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim nA As Long, nB As Long, v As Variant
   Dim a As Long, b As Long
   nA = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   nB = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

   For a = 1 To nA
      v = Cells(a, "A").Value
      For b = 1 To nB
         If Cells(b, "B").Value = v Then
            Cells(b, "B").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
         End If
      Next b
   Next a
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]